# Python open modes reset file before writing data

Tags: python, file, logging

I'm currently trying to reset files content using `with open(file, 'w') as foo:`

But the problem is that I need to execute script twice to view updated data in my file.

Steps I want to achieve:

(*executes script*)

1. Cleans files data
2. Writes data to file
3. Script finished it's job

Currently script does:

(*executes script*)

1. Cleans files data
2. Writes title to a file
3. Script finishes it's job

(*executes script again*)

4. Writes data to file
5. Now the file contains updated data

The code I have:

```
def write_updated_data(here_comes_data_as_list):
    header = 'File title here'
    with open(target_file, 'w') as tf:
        tf.write(header + '\n')
        [ tf.write(line + '\n') for line in here_comes_data_as_list ]
    print('Data is written..')
```

According to [fopen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/) man page mode `'w'`:

```
Truncate to zero length or create text file for writing.
The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file
```

If I understand correctly it will always cleans file before writting.

My question why it can't do that correctly? Does it can write once (like for my example writes header and finishes it's writting)?

Update:

By forcing to clean file is not working either, it writes the header to a file and then nothing follows:

```
def write_updated_data(here_comes_data_as_list):
    header = 'File title here'

    # forcing to clean file
    with open(target_file, 'w') as reset:
        reset.close()

    with open(target_file, 'a') as tf:
        tf.write(header + '\n')
        [ tf.write(line + '\n') for line in here_comes_data_as_list ]
    print('Data is written..')
```

Comment: Something is missing here , Im executing your code and my file that im writing to is cleaning itself everytime before running.

Do you want to clean on each execution or to update the file and not losing content on each run ?

Comment: @JimErginbash I want to clean the file at first and then write the data to it. In my case it's okay to loose data.

Comment: Are you sure your function is not cleaning the .txt file ? 
Because i just copied your code snippet and it does clean.

I can post an answer how you can keep your old data from the previous execution if needed.

Comment: @JimErginbash You can post as answer I'll take a look. By the way, I'm working with csv files, but I dont know if it makes any different.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using a `with` block, you don't need to explicitly `close()` the file handle. Also, abusing list comprehensions to write to a file is… confusing at best. You should do a traditional, simple `for line in here..: tf.write(line)`.

Comment: @JimErginbash i've added the header into list and still it only writes header. Bizzare..

Comment: You sure your list contains any data…?

Comment: @deceze to use for loop like this is just less code, yeah I can write a traditional one. But it wont change my problem. And  about ```close()``` good point, removed it, thanks.

Comment: *"Less code"* – Not really. `output = [ ... ]` is actually *more code*. If you're concerned about the *number of lines*, you could write `for .. in ..: ..` on one line. But then again, do you have a shortage of lines or something…? Reading over your code the first thing one notices is the unused variable `output`, so this takes more cognitive effort to really decipher.

Comment: @Poli using a list comprehension for side effects not only makes code harder to read (one expects list comprehensions to be used to create a new list), it also eats memory and cpu for no good reasons (building a list and creating a local variable dont come for free). Those are the reasons why it's considered bad practice. "it's less code" is not a valid reason to make your code both less readable and less efficient (specially when it's actually NOT "less code").

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaning the file:

```py
def write_updated_data(here_comes_data_as_list):
    header = 'File title here'
    with open(target_file, 'w') as tf:
        tf.write(header + '\n')
        output = [ tf.write(line + '\n') for line in here_comes_data_as_list ]
        tf.close()
    print('Data is written..')

write_updated_data(["fdfd","421"])
```

This is an option to run in order to just **update** the file:

```py
def file_before():
     r = open(target_file, 'r')
     content = r.read()
     r.close()
     return content

def write_updated_data(here_comes_data_as_list):
    previous_content = file_before()
    header = 'File title here'
    with open(target_file, 'w') as tf:
        tf.write(previous_content) # write the old content first
        tf.write(header + '\n')
        output = [ tf.write(line + '\n') for line in here_comes_data_as_list ]
        tf.close()
    print('Data is written..')

write_updated_data(["fd432432fd","421"])
```

If your list is filled behind scenes by some other code, check that it is not returning None or empty list 
(Try with a simple string like the above)

Comment: Besides it writes header everytime inside a file, it's a good solution.